# Is there a formal name for the dissolved caterpillar substance produced during metamorphosis?

Tags: entomology, terminology

Is there a formal name for the dissolved caterpillar substance produced during metamorphosis? I've seen this described as a protein-rich soup, a horrid meltdown, larval tissue breakdown, metamorphic goo, etc. Wondering if it has a more specific scientific name?